# dynamics crm 4.0 lookup field onload() query

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have an account entity with a lookup field `schoolLookupId` which refers back to a custom entity `new_schools`. The lookup field only display the name of the school. What I would like to be able to do using the `onload()` event handler of the account form is to run some javascript code that will query the `new_phonenumber` attribute of the `new_schools` entity to see if it matches a value i provide lets say `var x = "1234"` and if it does then update `schoolLookupId` accordingly with the name of the school that corresponds with the found phone number. i.e update the lookup field with a phone number that already exists **without** creating a completely new lookup value.

I can get the attributes of the lookupfield using

```
var name = crmForm.all.schoolLookupid.DataValue[0].name
var id = crmForm.all.schoolLookupid.DataValue[0].id
var typename = crmForm.all.schoolLookupid.DataValue[0].typename
```

but I can't figure out how to retrieve, compare the data that lies behind the lookup field, and update the lookupfield accordingly.

Your help as always is invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

Try put this code in load event:

```
   var xml = "" +  
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +  
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +  
    GenerateAuthenticationHeader() +  
    " <soap:Body>" +  
    " <RetrieveMultiple xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">" +  
    " <query xmlns:q1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query\" xsi:type=\"q1:QueryExpression\">" +  
    "        <q1:EntityName>new_schools</q1:EntityName>" + 
    "        <q1:ColumnSet xsi:type=\"q1:ColumnSet\">" + 
    "          <q1:Attributes>" + 
    "            <q1:Attribute>new_schoolsid</q1:Attribute>" + 
    "          </q1:Attributes>" + 
    "        </q1:ColumnSet>" + 
    "        <q1:Distinct>false</q1:Distinct>" + 
    "        <q1:Criteria>" + 
    "          <q1:FilterOperator>And</q1:FilterOperator>" + 
    "          <q1:Conditions>" + 
    "            <q1:Condition>" + 
    "              <q1:AttributeName>new_phonenumber</q1:AttributeName>" + 
    "              <q1:Operator>Equal</q1:Operator>" + 
    "              <q1:Values>" + 
    "                <q1:Value xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"+crmForm.all.new_phonenumber.DataValue+"</q1:Value>" + 
    "              </q1:Values>" + 
    "            </q1:Condition>" +
    "          </q1:Conditions>" + 
    "        </q1:Criteria>" + 
    " </query>" +  
    " </RetrieveMultiple>" +  
    " </soap:Body>" +  
    "</soap:Envelope>" +  
    "";  

    var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    xmlHttpRequest.Open("POST", "http://"+window.location.hostname+":"+window.location.port+"/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx", false);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction"," http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/RetrieveMultiple");  
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");  
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);  
    xmlHttpRequest.send(xml);  

    var resultXml = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;

    if (_resultXml.xml.search('<q1:new_schoolsid')>0)
    {
        var val = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("q1:new_schoolsid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        var lookupitem = new Array(); 
        lookupitem[0] = new LookupControlItem(val , typecode, name); 
        crmForm.all.schoolLookupid.DataValue = lookupitem ; 
    }
}
```

I don't try this code be careful. Use this code as a guide.

Hope this helps.
If i answered your question, please mark the response as an answer and also vote as helpful.

Comment: :First thanks for your help. I tried your code but it doesn't work. There was no JavaScript error so i commented it so I put an alert inside the if statement to see if i was actually hitting it and sure enough I wasn't..any other suggestions?